# Javascript function not being hit on change of element from partial view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have the following dropdown from a view model:

```
<div class="mdl-selectfield mdl-js-selectfield mdl-selectfield--floating-label">
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.QuoteModelSea.OriginAdd.Country, new SelectList(Model.QuoteModelSea.OriginAdd.CountryList, "Text", "Value"), "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "mdl-selectfield__select" })
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuoteModelSea.OriginAdd.Country, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "mdl-selectfield__label" })
</div>
```

This is in a partial view which is being attached to a div upon an ajax call.

Then in the main view I have a javascript:

```
$('#QuoteModelSea_OriginAdd_Country').change(function () {
        $('#searchTextField').val('');
       *actions*
});
```

The rendered html of the razor view is as follows:

```
<div class="mdl-selectfield mdl-js-selectfield mdl-selectfield--floating-label">
   <select id="QuoteModelSea_OriginAdd_Country" name="QuoteModelSea.OriginAdd.Country">
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value="1">abc</option>
     <option value="2">abc Islands</option>
     <option value="3">abc</option>
     <option value="4">abc</option>
   </select>
   <label class="mdl-selectfield__label" for="QuoteModelSea_OriginAdd_Country">Country</label>
</div>
```

However when I select a value from the dropdown, the javascript is not being hit.  The dropdown is in a partial view and the javascript in the main view.
Any idea why the javascript function is not being called?

Comment: At a guess, you're calling your javascript before [document ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: Check generated `<select>` element's id attribute from browser's dev tools, the value should be exactly matched with jQuery selector and the function must called inside `$(function() { ... })` block.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto : I have checked it both are exactly the same